# Symfony2 Query Builder Not Returning Many To One Value

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, doctrine-orm, query-builder

I have an entity that has a column "inventoryLcoation_id" that has a many to one relationship. For some reason when I use createQueryBuilder() it is not returning that value in my ajax call, but it returns everything else: id, name, etc etc.. This is not an issue with Symfony2, its an issue with my lack of knowledge :)

Here is my query builder code:

```
 $qb = $this
 ->createQueryBuilder('p')
 ->select('p.id', 'p.name')
 ->where('p.inventoryLocation = :inventoryId')
 ->andWhere('p.account = :account_id')
 ->setParameter('inventoryId', $value)
 ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id)
 ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC');
 if($qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult()){
      return $qb->getQuery()->getArrayResult();
 }else{
      return false;
 }
```

What do I need to code to have it also include the value from the **inventoryLocation** table which is mapped to the column value "inventoryLocation_id"?

Thanks so much for your help in enlightening my understanding to the awesome world of Symfony2!

Answer (score 0):

try a join:

```
$qb->join('p.inventoryLocation','i')
```

and in the select especify both entities

```
$qb->select('p','i')
```

it should look like this:

```
$qb = $this
 ->createQueryBuilder('p')
 ->select('p','i')
 ->join('p.inventoryLocation','i')
 ->where('p.inventoryLocation = :inventoryId') // or ->where('i = :inventoryId')
 ->andWhere('p.account = :account_id')
 ->setParameter('inventoryId', $value)
 ->setParameter('account_id', $account_id)
 ->orderBy('p.id', 'DESC');
```